# Tensorflow Dataset API with HDFS

Tags: tensorflow, hdfs, tensorflow-datasets

We have stored a list of *.tfrecord files in a HDFS directory. I'd like to use the new Dataset API  but the only example given is to use the old filequeue and string_input_producer (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/hadoop). These methods make it difficult to generate epochs amongst other things.

Is there any way to use HDFS with the Dataset API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The HDFS file system layer works with both the old queue-based API and the new `tf.data` API. Assuming you have configured your system according to the [TensorFlow/Hadoop deployment guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/hadoop), you can create a dataset based on files in HDFS with the following code:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["hdfs://namenode:8020/path/to/file1.tfrecords",
                                   "hdfs://namenode:8020/path/to/file2.tfrecords"])
dataset = dataset.map(lambda record: tf.parse_single_example(record, ...)
# ...
```

Note that since HDFS is a distributed file system, you might benefit from some of the suggestions in the ["Parallelize data extraction"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/performance/datasets_performance#parallelize_data_extraction) section of the Input Pipeline performance guide.

Comment: In distributed tensorflow training, with `tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave` loading data from hdfs, do I need to manually split the dataset into different directories in order to make each work reading different parts of the whole dataset?

Comment: Different directories is one way to do it, but you can also use `Dataset.list_files(..., shuffle=False).shard(num_workers, worker_id)` to ensure that each worker reads a different part of the set of files.

Comment: Your link is broken.